# What is the definition of a gradient?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

It has been a while since I have done any vector calculus,

is this statement true?

$\nabla f(x,y,z) = 0 \iff \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$

or is it only when the partials are equal to zero on their own individually?

Comment: You should first check the definition of the gradient on Wikipedia or something like that: a gradient (of a scalar function) is a **vector** function.

Comment: Of course, sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Never mind. Glad that I can help.

Comment: The gradient is zero when each component of the gradient is zero (since the gradient is a vector).  The partial derivatives are the components of the vector, so you need every partial derivative to be zero in order for the gradient to be zero.

Comment: Thanks travis, if you want to add that as an answer, i will accept it so you can get the reputation points..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient is a vector of partial derivatives, not a sum of partial derivatives. A vector is zero if and only if *each* of its components is zero.

Our, as [TravisJ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338676/what-is-the-definition-of-a-gradient/1340570#comment2720719_1338676) put it,

> The gradient is zero when each component of the gradient is zero (since the gradient is a vector). The partial derivatives are the components of the vector, so you need every partial derivative to be zero in order for the gradient to be zero.